# How to generate an RSA-SHA1 signature using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, rest, t-sql, rsa, sha1

G'day, I am currently tasked with creating a stored procedure with T-SQL which will be able to make a GET call using an MSXML2.serverXMLHttp instance that contains a *signed* OAuth authorization header.

I have been able to do everything short of generate the RSA-SHA1 signature string because I cannot find a hash_signing function.

I created the base string and generated the hash digest using the **HASHBYTES()** function, but am unable to find a corresponding hash signing function as the documentation is very confusing to me.

So, my question really boils down to: Is it possible to generate an RSA-SHA1 signature in T-SQL without using CLR or other external work-arounds? And if so which functions are required to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can access .Net functionality using [CLR Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration)

Comment: Stepping back a bit, I'd think, do I want my database server making HTTP calls to external web servers, maybe this data should be pushed in my another part of my infrastructure. However, that is tangential to the question and better directed to the architect of your solution.

Comment: I understand what you're saying completely Jodrell but unfortunately the project I am working on has fixed constraints and needs the request to be dealt with using an internal stored procedure without using CLR. Sorry about that but I do appreciate the help.